# PHP How to find string after Match/Wildcard/Match

Tags: php, regex, string

Say I have the following string, $mytext:

```
[QUOTE=FirstUserRANDOMNUMBER]First user's post[/QUOTE]

Great post, FirstUser

[QUOTE=SecondUserRANDOMNUMBER]Second user's post[/QUOTE]

Awful post. I didn't like it.
```

Given a Username, how can I find the text below the quoted User? (ignoring RANDOMNUMBER)

I want to be able to input "SecondUser" into a function and have it return: "Awful post. I didn't like it."

Basically, I just want the response to the quoted user.

I thought I'd do a substr on $mytext based on the following:

```
strpos($username, $mytext) + strlen("[QUOTE=$username") + strlen("[/QUOTE]")
```

But I don't know how to get the length of the wildcard text in between [QUOTE=$username and the next instance of [/quote]

This must support the occurrence of multiple quotes in $mytext, like the example above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\[QUOTE=SecondUser.*\[\/QUOTE\]([^[]*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/yS1cR0/1)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't seem to be working with preg_match:

`$mytext = "[QUOTE=SecondUserRANDOMNUMBER]Second user's post[/QUOTE]Test test test";`

`preg_match('\[QUOTE=SecondUser.*\[\/QUOTE\]([^[]*)', $mytext, $matches);`

`echo $matches[0];` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @PFBilling It works on regex101 http://regex101.com/r/yS1cR0/2. Btw, you can check the Code Generator section to copy the content.

Comment: This must be an issue with my PHP code. Thanks very much for the regex - marking Accepted, as the regex is exactly what we need.

Comment: @PFBilling you aren't puting slash for your regex: `$re = "/\\[QUOTE=SecondUser.*\\[\\/QUOTE\\]([^[]*)/"; `

Comment: @PFBilling glad to help. Thanks for the tick. Btw, check my comment above, you have an issue on your preg_match. Use `preg_match('/\\[QUOTE=SecondUser.*\\[\\/QUOTE\\]([^[]*)/', $mytext, $matches);` instead

Comment: One more quick question @Fede - is it possible to have it stop at the next instance of "[QUOTE" instead of just "[" ? The problem is that we have a lot of other bbcode, like [url], so the text is getting cut off too soon for some posts.

Comment: Thanks again! This works great (and also with new lines) : \[QUOTE=SecondUser.*\[\/QUOTE\]([\s\S]+?(?=\[QUOT))

Answer (score 1):

Search for, but don't capture (within `(...)` groups) everything you want to exclude. In this case, `\[Quote.*`. Then search for (and capture) everything you DO want to keep. It will be saved in the `\1` reference:

```
^\[QUOTE.*\n+|(^.*$)
```

It will *match* the `[QUOTE...]` line, but it doesn't *capture* that line: The only lines that are kept are

```
Great post, FirstUser
Awful post. I didn't like it.
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/gB6hO2/1)